# custom font selector for interactive SVG

Tags: svg, fonts

I have an SVG image (logo) that contains SVG text element. I want to provide users with ability to change font of the text via list UI (drop down list), so that if user clicks the drop down list they can see how will this text look like approximately after selection. If selected such font attributes would apply to the SVG text element.

Right now I feel like I don't understand how would I learn for a particular user's browser/system which fonts are available.

I read SVG fonts specs and it is still confusing.

One approach I found is:
- I pre-bake the list based on assumptions (lets say we list all popular fonts)
- show this list to user who could see on their own whether the applied font is looking good for them
- If users selects an option that is not supported by their system - it will be matched by closest "equivalent" font (according to the specs)

But this is suboptimal as I want to guarantee what this user will generate as SVG logo will look the same for all other users.

Then I was thinking to embed the fonts I liked from fonts.google.com into my web-site and list those?

**So given the description and requirements to make the font choice consistent across many users - what should be my approach?**

Comment: Does that approach (local font list) make sense?  What if the user has a font that no other users have?  I think your idea at the end re having a set of Google fonts, is the better approach.

Comment: yes I also think more and more that this is the path;) but I thought that I want someone to confirm that. Btw just in general I think fonts.google.com is awesome service...